# Django RestFramework call the Api by the Field

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

currently i pass the parameter 'id' in the url and i call the API by id however i would like to call API by the parameter.here is views.py`

```html
class post_list(APIView):

    def get(self,request,format=None):
        post_resource=PostResource()
        dataset=Dataset()
        post = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(post, many=True)
        a=[]
        for row in post:
            a.append(row)

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self,request,format =None):
        serializer = PostSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=400)




class post_detail(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Post.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        post = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = PostSerializer(snippet,    data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        post = self.get_object(pk)
        post.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

this is the result when i pass the id in the url[image]`

when i pass the id in the url it's show only the that particular id result however i need view if i pass the other field instead of the id it's show the result based on that.so my question is what should i have to change in the views.py and Urls.py. this is urls.py file`

```html
from django.conf.urls import url
from api import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^post/$', views.post_list.as_view()),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail.as_view()),

]
urlpatterns=format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

This is my serializer.py file`

```html
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post


class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post

        #fields=('ProductName','Score')
        fields ='__all__'
```

`

Comment: It depends on what you want to pass instead of `id`. What type is it? is it a string? or a `uuid`?

Comment: I would like to pass the "PName" which is string.

Comment: Most likely you want query parameters, so that you can filter by other field.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your url so that it accepts string:

```
 url(r'^post/(?P<pname>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail.as_view())
```

and then change your `get_object` method like this:

```
def get_object(self, pname):
    try:
        return Post.objects.get(pname=pname)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

But you will issues if `pname` is not unique, because it will complain that you have more than one such Post.

Hope it helps!